# How to solve the potential ClassCastException here?

Tags: java, classcastexception

There is a class that already exists:

```
public class TermsBuilder extends ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder<TermsBuilder> {
    ...
}
```

And a class that uses it:

```
public class TermsClass {
    ...
    ((TermsBuilder) ret).runSomeFunction();
}
```

I created a class `TermsBuilderWrapper` and used it like:

```
public class TermsClass {
    ...
    ((TermsBuilderWrapper) ret).runSomeOtherFunction();
}
```

where `ret` is a `DateHistogramBuilder` class object:

```
public class DateHistogramBuilder extends ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder<DateHistogramBuilder> {
    ...
}
```

But I am getting a warning `Casting 'ret' to 'TermsBuilderWrapper' may produce 'java.lang.ClassCastException'`.

What could be wrong here?

UPDATE:

I implemented the `TermsBuilderWrapper` like:

```
public class TermsBuilderWrapper extends ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder<TermsBuilder> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting it to `TermsBuilder` if it is of type `DateHistogramBuilder`? Aside from their super class, they're unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TermsBuilder` or `DateHistogramBuilder` class needs to implement the `TermsBuilderWrapper` if you want to cast either in this manner.

It should also be noted, that to be used in this manner, `TermsBuilderWrapper` need to be an interface and not a class. Java doesn't support extending multiple classes.

```
public class DateHistogramBuilder implements TermsBuilderWrapper {
    ...
}
```

Also an `interface` cannot `extend` a class. `TermsBuilderWrapper` needs to be redefined thusly,

```
public interface TermsBuilderWrapper {
    ...
}
```

After making the interface, declare the methods you want to be available in it's body.

```
public interface TermsBuilderWrapper {
    public Object runSomeFunction();
    public Object runSomeOtherFunction();
}
```

Comment: It's still a different object class in Java's eyes.. I'll update my answer to show what I'm meaning.

Answer (score 0):

ret is DateHistogramBuilder, which mean it's also a ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder, however to cast "anything" to TermsBuilder, "anything" needs to be a descendant of TermsBuilder.

I suggest you read a bit more about inheritance, because it looks like you still have some gaps.